# How do I connect to LivePerson agent hub with bot framework emulator

Tags: node.js, botframework, liveperson

I have a bot implemented in `node.js` which is running in Azure.

1. It utilizes the directline channel.
2. Uses knowledge bases hosted on qna maker.
3. Uses Luis for language understanding.

My bot works perfectly fine with bot framework emulator however I want to route the message to LivePerson agent hub for special utterances `Talk to live person/connect to customer care/speak to someone/Need human assistant`. And once it is connected to agent hub user chats to live person from bot emulator and someone logged in agent hub replies with all the queries.

I configured this [Tompaana's LivePerson-bot-adapter](https://github.com/tompaana/liveperson-bot-adapter) repository with LivePerson `Keys/creds` but it does not work.

Doc here [Third party bot connection to LivePerson](https://knowledge.liveperson.com/ai-bots-automation-third-party-bot-connectors.html)  is also not much helpful. Can someone please please help how do I connect to live person agent hub from bot framework emulator.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the third-party bot connector available in LivePerson to achieve this.
Please refer to this [doc](https://developers.liveperson.com/third-party-bots-microsoft-direct-line-introduction.html).

You can also define welcome messages for each engagement created in LivePerson. For this, you have to define the welcome message in the engagement studio (Window customization tab).